# When I open my flutter app it always shows Sign In screen for few seconds, even if I already signed In in my last session. And after that Main page?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return GetMaterialApp(

        localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,

        supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,

        locale: context.locale,

        navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,

        color: Colors.white,

        getPages: router.routes,

        initialRoute: SignInPageRoute,

        routingCallback: (routing) {

          final _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();

          final _authService = locator<AuthService>();

          if (routing!.current == SignInPageRoute) {

            WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
              (_) {
                bool isLoggedIn = _authService.isLoggedIn();
                if (isLoggedIn) {
                  _navigationService.offAllTo(MainPageRoute);
                } else {
                  return;
                }
              },
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: i would recomment to shift your authentication logic in splash screen and then either show login or main page based on successfull authentication

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```html
bool isLoggedIn = await _authService.isLoggedIn();
```